# Spark SQL .distinct() performance

Tags: sql, apache-spark, duplicates, distinct

I want to source few hundreds of gigabytes from a database via JDBC and then process it using Spark SQL. Currently I am doing some partitioning at that data and process is by batches of milion records. The thing is that I would like also to apply some deduplication to my dataframes and I was going to leave that idea of separated batches processing and try to process those hundreds of gigabytes using a one dataframe partitioned accordingly.

The main concern is: how will .distinct() work in such case? Will Spark SQL firstly try to load ALL the data into the RAM and then apply deduplication involving many shuffles and repartitioning? Do I have to ensure that a cluster has enough of RAM to contain that raw data or maybe it will be able to help itself with HDD storage (thus killing the performance)?

Or maybe I should do it without Spark - move the data to the target storage and there apply distinct counts and detect duplicates and get rid off them?

Answer (score 4):

Spark SQL does NOT use [predicate pushdown](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12957) for `distinct` queries; meaning that the processing to filter out duplicate records happens at the executors, rather than at the database. So, your assumption regarding shuffles happening over at the executors to process `distinct` is correct.

Inspite of this, I would still advise you to go ahead and perform the de-duplication on Spark, rather than build a separate arrangement for it. My personal experience with `distinct` has been more than satisfactory. It has always been the joins which push my buttons.